How to show snackbar on top of bottom buttons
I have this layout with data binding and coordinator Layout, which contains button on bottom which hides while scrolling down. I want to show Snackbar on this screen, but if i show it, it shows above the button, but i want it to be on top of button
Here is layout:
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
         ...
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainCoordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...


    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            ...
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                .../>
    </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>

This is how i show snackbar:
Snackbar.make(ContextThemeWrapper(binding.root.context), binding.root, message, length).show()

i've tried to make this framelayout gone but snackbar still shows above this area where button should be

You can use a custom layout for your snackbar. By defining a bottom padding in your layout, you can achieve showing it on top of bottom buttons.
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottom_buttons_height">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/big_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/big_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Toast message." />
        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

Then you can use this layout in your snackbar:
val snackBar = Snackbar.make(
    this.getActivityRootView(),
    "",
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
)
val snackBarLayout: View = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_snackbar_layout, null)
snackBar.view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
(snackBar.view as ViewGroup).apply {
    removeAllViews()
    addView(snackBarLayout)
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
}
snackBar.show()

